# Why doesn't Android studio provide enough time for an emulator to statrtup?

Tags: android, emulation

I use the latest Android emulator ( API 23) and it takes a lot of time to start up, when I run my app from the Android Studio, after some time, the message reads 
"
07/21 11:49:52: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
"
So, my question is that why doesn't the Studio provide enough time for the app to launch up? Why is the Android studio designed that way?
Second Question:
Poll: Do you think that there are still a lot of errors in the Android SDK, Emulator and studio?

Answer (score 1):

basically major reason is slow performance of the computer hardware .usually if you have `virtualization support` in your hardware then emulator just work fine as a real device so make sure u have and the emulator image you are using must be the VT supported image,the arm images are 10 times slow

other factors could also effect your system performance if you are using emulator

- ram 8gb for better emulator performance
- android studio and emulator version (use updated one)

otherwise you can try genymotion AVD's but they also required VT support

Comment: by the way some processors have Vt but it could be disable so you can check that in your bios .just search on google "enable VT support in biso" and step will be there in front of you though people recommend testing app on real devices because a real device can behave in a far different way